# How can strumming be blended with finger picking on nylon string in a new arrangement?

Tags: guitar, technique

While arranging Warlock's Capriol Suite for guitar (# 1,2,3,5,6 sound nice), I thought #4 would work with a fair amount of strumming the phrases and finger picking the runs. Looking for ideas on

1. how to bring out the melody while strumming the rhythmic phrases
2. technique for switching back and fourth between strumming and finger picking.

As a classical guitar hobbyist I'm discovering the holes in my education.

Answer (score 2):

(2) You can strum without a pick fairly easily, which makes switching back and forth just a matter of practice.

As a result of (2), you tend to have more dynamic control (i.e. for multi instrumental arrangements, the strummer can be quieter than the melody; for solo arrangements you can emphasize the bass or treble side of the strum).